# Maven can't find tools.jar

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am working on a Spring STS project using Eclipse and when I try to run my unit tests using **Run as > Maven test** I have the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile)
        on project eshop-sample-spring-legacy: Fatal error compiling: tools.jar not found: 
        C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_144\..\lib\tools.jar -> [Help 1]
```

I have Java 8 update 144 installed and my variable environments set as follow:

```
JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
JRE_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre
Path = ...;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\bin;C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre\bin;...
```

My `C:\Program Files\Java` folder contains `jdk1.8.0_144` and `jre1.8.0_144` installation folders.

In Eclipse I set **Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs** pointing to `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144\jre`.

Can somebody help me? Thanks

Comment: You point to a JRE.  JRE's explicitly does not contain the javac compiler.  Note that you can circumvent this by telling maven to use the eclipse compiler, but I think using the JDK is better for you for now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your *Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs* is pointing to JRE. But *tools.jar*  is not part of the JRE.

So you need to configure your

```
Windows > Preferences > Java > Installed JREs
```

to point to

```
C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_144
```

or where ever you installed your JDK.

Answer (score 2):

Make `INSTALLED_JRE` point to `JDK`